# Count occurrences of each digit in number using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program using arrays, which takes a number and returns the number of incidents of each digit within that number. I think I may be overcomplicating things here.

```
import java.util.*;
class Exercice7 {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Veuillez saisir un nombre naturel:");   // Get number

    int n = sc.nextInt();                                       // Store number as n

    String str = Integer.toString(n);                           // Store n as string

    int length = str.length();                                    // Store string length as length

    int arr[] = new int[length];                                // Declare array with as many elements as n has digits

    int digit[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};                        // Declare array with the digits to look for

    int count = 0;                                                // Number of occurences of each digit

    for (int i=(length-1); i>=0; i--) {                         // Fill array with digits from number input
        while (n>0) {
            arr[i]= n%10;
            n = n/10;
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]==digit[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count>0) {
        System.out.println(digit[j] + " occurs " + count + " times.");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This code only returns the number of 0s and 1s and it's wrong anyway. Could someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare array with ten elements ([0..9]) - there you will have occurences of each digit in your number. Simply using `counts[3]` will get you number of occurences of digit `3`.

Then you just iterate over string number and read next char as integer and increase counter. This way you have only one loop. For example, having `3` in your number, you use `counts[3]++`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but it seems to work!

Comment: Well I am glad you've make it work - this is why I didn't provide any code. It's much better and more fun, when you make your own answer for (hard?) question. Good job, man, even if my way is a little different :)

Comment: Thanks, deem! I totally agree. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try converting to String and read each char

```
int counts[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};  
int myNumber=123222;//example
String string=""+myNumber; //converting integer to String

for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
 try{
   int n=Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(i)+"")
   counts[n]=counts[n]+1;
 }catch(Exception e){}

}
```

then to print it out:

```
for (int i=0; i<counts.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i] + " times.");
}
```

Comment: The counts array should have all elements at 0 when initialised since the values represent the count of each digit rather than the digit itself (which is represented by the index).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, [deem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176698/deem), for your answer. I didn't completely understand what you meant, but it helped me get on the right track:

```
import java.util.*;
class Exercice7 {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Veuillez saisir un nombre naturel:"); //* Get number */
    int num = sc.nextInt(); //* Store number as n */
    String str = Integer.toString(num); //* Store n as string *//

    char digit[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<(str.length()); j++) {
            if (str.charAt(j) == digit[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count>0) {
            System.out.println(digit[i] + " apparait " + count + " fois.");
            count = 0;
        }            
    }
}
}
```

It may not be the easiest way, but it works! Feel free to add more comments if you want to make improvements to the code.